# Windows 8 stopped recognizing My Passport Ultra Drive

Tags: windows-8, usb, external-hard-drive

I have Windows 8 on Dell Inspiron 15 R laptop.

I purchased a Brand new My Passport Ultra Drive.

For past two weeks I plugged in My Passport Ultra Drive and created System Image.

This week, my computer will not recognize the My Passport drive. When I plug in the Passport drive, I hear sound from computer and see light on Passport drive.

When I go to Device Manager I see this

[image]

According to [this link](http://ccm.net/forum/affich-650763-western-digital-my-passport-not-detected), I right-clicked and uninstalled the drive. Then I right clicked on USB and selected "Scan for hardware changes" and I still get the same Yellow triangle with "Unknown USB Device ..."

Comment: Does it work on other pcs?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have access to other PCs right now. But I do know that I can plug other things into this PC.

Comment: Plugging in other devices doesn't confirm the HDD is functional

Comment: If you are still within the return/exchange period I would get rid of it while you still can.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I solved my own problem, hope this helps others, despite the downvotes!

Answer (score 1):

I believed this problem was solved

1. I upgraded to Windows 10 and when problem persisted I called WD tech support and they asked me to open Disk Management
2. Passport drive was healthy partition
3. Tech Support said they will mail me free cable to "boost power"
4. When I got off the phone I went to Disk Management and assigned Drive to Passport
5. Passport now appears in Windows Explorer

In response to fixer1234:

(1) I upgraded to Win 10 as part of troubleshooting solution. However, this fix may also work for Win 8.

(2) Problem was fixed before cable arrived (will be shipped tomorrow)

(3) Yes, key to solution is assigning a drive letter to drive in Disk Management. BUT when I inserted Passport into another USB drive on the same laptop, the partition did not even appear in Disk Management

Comment: Can you clarify a couple of things?  1) Did you upgrade to Win 10 as part of the solution, or was that just coincidental (in which case your fix may also work in Win 8)?  2) I'm guessing the cable was a "Y" cable to supply extra power to the drive.  Are you saying you fixed it before the cable even came (the problem is unrelated to power and the cable isn't needed as part of the solution)?  3) Was the key to the solution just assigning a drive letter to the drive in Disk Management?  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 I updated my answer for you.

Comment: re: last item in your edit -- these may duplicate things already tried, but a couple of links with things to try just in case not: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2654149 and http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/external-drive-not-recognized-this-is-how-to-fix-it-in-windows/

Comment: @fixer1234 Thank you for the links